# Telerik Grid action link with if condition in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik-grid

I'm using Telerik Grid.

I have 2 columns "status" and "View Details"

In column bound of "View Details" I have to check the "status" column value.

if it is success then I have to give link to the "View Details" column.

on click of view details I'm calling javascript and it continues.

I have written code like below.

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Status).Width(150).Title("Status").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });

columns.Bound(o => o.ViewDetails).Width(50).Title("View Details").ClientTemplate("#  
if (Status == 'success') 
    { #" + @Html.ActionLink("View Details", "", "", new { onclick = "return onLinkClickViewDetails('<#= MyParameter #>');" },  
    new { @Title = "see" }).ToHtmlString() + "# } 
else {#"View Details"#} #").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align:center" });
```

If the "status" column's data is Success then I have to show ViewDetail as a link
otherwise I have to show it as a text.

I cant figure out what is wrong in this code.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *inline* `if else`, something like this:

```
.ClientTemplate("<a href='" +
((y == 0/*Put your condition here*/)?Url.Action("edit", "some"):"") + "/#= edit_Id #'" + ">Edit</a>");
```